# How to split up an Iterator?

Tags: scala, collections, iterator

How to split an iterator into a prefix with duplicates and the rest ? For instance,

```
def splitDupes(it: Iterator[Int]): (Iterator[Int], Iterator[Int]) = ???

val (xs, ys) = splitDupes(List(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5).iterator)
xs.toList // List(1, 1, 1)
ys.toList // List(2, 3, 4, 5)

val (xs, ys) = splitDupes(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).iterator)
xs.toList // List(1)
ys.toList // List(2, 3, 4, 5)

val (xs, ys) = splitDupes(List(1, 1, 1, 1, 1).iterator)
xs.toList // List(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
ys.toList // List()

val (xs, ys) = splitDupes(List[Int]().iterator)
xs.toList // List()
ys.toList // List()
```

Can I use it to read a text file by chunks ?

Comment: What happens in the case of List(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1) ?

Comment: (1) and (2, 3, 4, 1, 1)

Comment: This is a bit tricky. I assume there is the precondition that, ideally, you do this without reading the entire file/list. In that case, fold, partition etc. are out of the question. I can only think of (xs, ys) = (...takeWhile(), ....drop(n)) which would be O(2n) = O(n) where n is the length of the prefix

Comment: Yes, I don't want to read the whole file. Thanks for the suggestion anyway :)

Comment: No problem. If the takeWhile & drop approach doesn't make sense, I can write a quick example if you wish

Comment: Thanks again. No need for example for now ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `span` method to split an `Iterable` into a prefix that satisfies a predicate and a suffix that doesn't. For `Iterator`s `span` does the correct thing, and lazily stores elements in the prefix `Iterator`, in case the suffix was iterated before the prefix has run out.

```
def splitDupes[T](it: Iterator[T]): (Iterator[T], Iterator[T]) = {
  if (it.isEmpty) (Iterator.empty, Iterator.empty)
  else {
    val head = it.next()
    val (dupes, rest) = it.span(_ == head)
    (Iterator(head) ++ dupes, rest)
  }
}
```

Example:

```
scala> val (dupes, rest) = splitDupes(Iterator(1,1,1,2,3,2,1))
dupes: Iterator[Int] = <iterator>
rest: Iterator[Int] = <iterator>

scala> (dupes.toList, rest.toList)
res1: (List[Int], List[Int]) = (List(1, 1, 1),List(2, 3, 2, 1))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This `span` is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this?
*(Note: I decided to return a plain **List** as the first part since that would already been consumed)*

```
def splitDupes[A](it: Iterator[A]): (List[A], Iterator[A]) = {
  it.nextOption() match {
    case Some(head) =>
      @annotation.tailrec
      def loop(count: Int): (List[A], Iterator[A]) =
        it.nextOption() match {
          case Some(x) if (x == head) =>
            loop(count + 1)

          case Some(x) =>
            List.fill(count)(head) -> Iterator(Iterator.single(x), it).flatten

          case None =>
            List.fill(count)(head) -> Iterator.empty
        }

      loop(count = 1)

    case None =>
      List.empty -> Iterator.empty
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Liked the idea of returning the first part as a `List` !

Comment: @Michael Of course, if you want, you can call `.iterator` before returning, but IMHO that wouldn't be of much help. Also, please note that I used **Scala** `2.13` you can replicate the code for `2.12` you just need to change `nextOption()` with `if (it.hasNext) it.next()`.