# Transforming an iterator into an iterator of chunks of duplicates

Tags: scala, iterator

Suppose I am writing a function `foo: Iterator[A] => Iterator[List[A]]` to transform a given iterator into an iterator of chunks of duplicates :

```
def foo[T](it: Iterator[A]): Iterator[List[A]] = ???
foo("abbbcbbe".iterator).toList.map(_.mkString) // List("a", "bbb", "c", "bb", "e")
```

In order to implement `foo` I want to reuse function `splitDupes: Iterator[A] => (List[A], Iterator[A])` that splits an iterator into a prefix with duplicates and the rest (thanks a lot to [Kolmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1098230/kolmar) who suggested it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59142798/how-to-split-up-an-iterator))

```
def splitDupes[A](it: Iterator[A]): (List[A], Iterator[A]) = {
  if (it.isEmpty) {
    (Nil, Iterator.empty)
  } else {
    val head = it.next
    val (dupes, rest) = it.span(_ == head)
    (head +: dupes.toList, rest)
  }
}
```

Now I am writing `foo` using `splitDupes` like that:

```
def foo[A](it: Iterator[A]): Iterator[List[A]] = {
   if (it.isEmpty) {
     Iterator.empty
   } else {
     val (xs, ys) = Iterator.iterate(splitDupes(it))(x => splitDupes(x._2)).span(_._2.nonEmpty)
     (if (ys.hasNext) xs ++ Iterator(ys.next) else xs).map(_._1)
   }
}
```

This implementation seems working but it's look complicated and clumsy.
How would you improve the `foo` implementation above ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
def foo[A](it: Iterator[A]): Iterator[List[A]] = {
  Iterator.iterate(splitDupes(it))(x => splitDupes(x._2))
    .map(_._1)
    .takeWhile(_.nonEmpty)
}
```

The empty case is already handled in `splitDupes`. You can safely keep calling `splitDupes` until it hits this empty case (that is, starts returning `Nil` in the first tuple element).

This works ok in all cases:

```
scala> foo("abbbcbbe".iterator).toList.map(_.mkString)
res1: List[String] = List(a, bbb, c, bb, e)

scala> foo("".iterator).toList.map(_.mkString)
res2: List[String] = List()

scala> foo("a".iterator).toList.map(_.mkString)
res3: List[String] = List(a) 

scala> foo("aaa".iterator).toList.map(_.mkString)
res4: List[String] = List(aaa)

scala> foo("abc".iterator).toList.map(_.mkString)
res5: List[String] = List(a, b, c)
```